# Manipulation of single <li> items in a <nav><ul></ul></nav>

Tags: html, css

I am creating a custom side navigation for one of my home projects and I recently was informed that instead of using several `<nav>` tags and placing them manually I should use a single `<nav>` and then a list on the inside. This however, has caused issues the replication of the way the side nav I had set up works

The following `.css` is the code which produces the format of the side navigation

```
nav {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  right: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3000;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-out !important;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-out !important;
  transition: all 250ms ease-out !important;
  border: 1mm;
  border-color: #CCCCFF;
  border-left-style: solid; 
}

#topnav:hover, 
#nav2:hover, 
#nav3:hover, 
#nav4:hover, 
#nav5:hover, 
#nav6:hover, 
#botnav:hover {
  z-index: 5000;
  width: 3cm;
  background-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-right-style: none;
  color: white;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4mm;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4mm;
  border-top-left-radius: 4mm;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4mm;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4mm;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4mm; 
}

nav:hover span {
  display: none; 
}

#topnav {
  top: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border-top-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4mm;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4mm;
  border-top-left-radius: 4mm; 
}

#topnav:hover:before {
  content: "Top"; 
}

#nav2 {
  top: 140px;
  background-color: red; 
}

#nav2:hover:before {
  content: "Red"; 
}

#nav3 {
  top: 180px;
  background-color: blue; 
}

#nav3:hover:before {
  content: "blue"; 
}

#nav4 {
  top: 220px;
  background-color: green; 
}

#nav4:hover:before {
  content: "green"; 
}

#nav5 {
  top: 260px;
  background-color: purple; 
}

#nav5:hover:before {
  content: "purple"; 
}

#nav6 {
  top: 300px;
  background-color: orange; 
}

#nav6:hover:before {
  content: "orange"; 
}

#botnav {
  top: 340px;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4mm;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4mm;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4mm; 
}

#botnav:hover:before {
  content: "200"; 
}
```

This can be seen put in place on the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/1hz9fnoL/)

Whilst editing my code I have had an issue when you hover over a list item. When the `<li>` item extends, it extends the `<nav>` and the `<ul>` as well. This is not what I intended it to do. I intended it to only extend `<li>` item.

```
.sidenav {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  right: 0px;
  top: 10%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3000;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1mm;
  border-color: #CCCCFF;
  border-style: solid;
  border-right-style: none;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4mm;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4mm;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4mm;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4mm;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4mm;
  border-top-left-radius: 4mm; 
}

.sidenav ul {
  list-style-type: none; 
}

.sidenav li {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-out !important;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-out !important;
  transition: all 250ms ease-out !important; 
}

.sidenav li:hover {
  width: 3cm;
  background-color: white; 
}
```

This can be seen put in place in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/7urgbrk2/).

I thought this might be able to be masked by setting the `text-align: right` and then change the `text-align` of the `<li>` item being hovered over, only when it was being hovered over. This works however it then meant the whole of the border moved out instead of only the border around the `<li>` item being hovered over and the background colours of the `<li>` items are also extended out instead of just the one being hovered over.

**The question**

Essentially my question is how do I need to edit my css so that the nav bar which is structured like

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

behave in the same way my first structure shown in the first [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/1hz9fnoL/) did? How can I manipulate a single `<li>` tag without effecting the whole `<ul>` or `<nav>`?

Comment: One small thing I noticed in your code is that it's not valid for `a` to be a direct child of `ul`, only `li` is a valid child.

Comment: You could avoid the list altogether and just use `<a>` elements inside one `<nav>` You can also create the single letters with a `data-*` attribute. [Example if interested](https://jsbin.com/yoruco/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: @misterManSam I'm a little confused on what your example is there is just a shape with a top which is spinning around. Can you explain how this relates?

Comment: JsBin is like jsfiddle. Looks like it's having problems loading so the site must be down. On the move now so can't explain more!

Comment: @misterManSam Oh okay. I will try the link again later. Thank you for posting

Comment: @misterManSam The link works now. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the reason that the `sidenav` is expanding when the `li` elements do, is because there's no explicit width placed on that parent element. So it's defaulting to `width: auto`. Thus, when the `li` elements expand, so does the parent. I've got a solution working that approximates your original example.

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7urgbrk2/2/).

I only made a few small updates to get it working. Here they are:

```
.sidenav {
  width: 40px;
}

.sidenav li {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
}

.sidenav li:hover {
  right: 200%;
}
```

Note, these are styles added in addition to what was already there, nothing removed. Hopefully this at least helps you get on the right path with this new solution!